# Compare to Generic List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, compare, equality

I need to compare 2 generic list for equality.
IEquatable< T> interface is a good way but i cant use
this because myObject has 15 properties and some properties are generic list again. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx

What is the best way?

Comment: Define equal first. What properties do you have, what can be different, what must be the same, does the case matter(in case of `string`), does the order matter(in case of the main list or the property lists)?

Comment: So use this oneinstead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073.aspx

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to accomplish. Why is it a problem that you have list-typed properties? Just include them in your object's `Equals()` implementation.

Comment: SequenceEqual with custom IEqualityComparer ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073.aspx